# Solving ODEs via substitution comparing with double integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm in the process of refreshing my mind with solving some 'basic' ODE's, I'm relatively proficient with mathematica, however being able to do some of these by hand would be preferable, as I don't always have MMA available to me.

Using an example of

$$\frac{\partial \left( x \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)}{\partial x}=0$$

The solution is: $$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to c_1 \ln (x)+c_2\right\}\right\}$$

I know this solely because MMA told me so.

One possible solution would be to integrate twice for x,

$$\int \frac{\partial \left(x \frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x}\right)}{\partial x} \, dx=\int 0 \, dx$$

then

$$\int y'(x) \, dx=\int \frac{c_1}{x} \, dx$$

with my solution being

$$y(x)=D[1]+c_1 \log (x)$$

Great,

Though if I remember correctly, I can use Z substitution, or D'lambert (though, I can't remember the method, nor with function would be appropriate to replace with)

Trying with Z substitution:

$$\frac{\partial \left( x \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)}{\partial x}=0$$

I differentiate to get:

$$x y''(x)+y'(x)=0$$

Apply Z sub with z = y' and z' = y''

$$z'=\frac{-z}{x}$$

At this point, I can seperate and intergrate giving me:

$$\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{z^2}{2}$$

And I know at this point, I am not going to get the correct solution.

So My question is, how do I solve this particular ODE via Substitution or D'lambart

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to double check your separating and integrating of $z' = -\dfrac{z}{x}$ (it seems like you got $\color{red}{z\, dz = x\, dx}$, but unfortunately this is not correct). Once you have $z' = -\dfrac{z}{x}\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{dz}{dx} = - \dfrac{z}{x}$ (so $\color{blue}{\frac{1}{z}\, dz = -\frac{1}{x}\, dx}$), separating and integrating gives $$\int \frac{1}{z}
\,dz = -\int \frac{1}{x}\, dx\Rightarrow \ln z = -\ln x + C.$$
(Also, remember to put in a $+C$ when doing the integration.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Your separation of variables is wrong:
$$z' = -\frac{z}{x}$$
means that
$$ \frac{\mathrm d z}{\mathrm d x} = - \frac{z}{x}$$
and thus
$$  \frac{1}{z} \mathrm d  z = -\frac{1}{x} \mathrm d x$$

Integrating gives you
$$\log (z) = -\log(x)+ K_1$$
Taking the exponential on both sides gives
$$ z = K_2\frac{1}{ x} \qquad (K_2 = \mathrm e^{K_1})$$

Substituting back $y'$ and separating the variables again you find the solution.